# The joint density of two dependent —yet uncorrelated— normal variables

Tags: distributions, density-function

Consider [this setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#A_symmetric_example).

Let $X$ be a standard normal variable. Let $I$ be a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p= 0.5$. Let $Y$ be equal to $(2I - 1)\cdot X$.

In the link I provided it is shown that the distribution of $Y$ is identical to the distribution of $X$ —i.e. it is also a standard normal— and that their covariance is $0$. However, they are not independent and, therefore, although each variable is individually normal, they are not *jointly* normal.

I have searched about this problem on the web and the focus of the explanation is to reach the same final conclusion: what $X$ and $Y$ are not. I, on the other hand, would like to know what $X$ and $Y$ actually are. I mean: ok, if they are not jointly normal, then what are they? **What is their joint pdf?**

And no, I'm not asking for $f_Z(z)$ where $Z = X + Y$. I'm asking for $f_{X, Y}(x, y)$.

Comment: $Y$ cannot be identical to $X$ since half the time it has the opposite sign. What is the same are their distributions; I have edited accordingly (and corrected a minor typo). You may find it enlightening to generate a random sample from (X,Y) and look at a scatterplot. In R this would be x=rnorm(1000); b=rbinom(1000,1,.5)*2-1;y=x*b; plot(x,y)

Comment: "Y is identical to X" is incorrect. Y and X have identical distributions. As for the joint distribution, in this case it's not a joint density. On the xy-plane, the probability distribution (more precisely, probability measure) is supported on the x-axis, y = x, and y = -x. This can be computed immediately.

Comment: @Michael Sorry to bother you with my ignorance. When I read your assertion that this joint distribution is not a joint density, my mind jumps into thinking that we are talking about a joint PMF. Certainly that must not be the case since both variables are continuous. I just didn’t know it was possible for two continuous variables to have a joint distribution that is not a joint density. Could you please enlighten me on the subject?

Comment: It's neither a pmf or a pdf, in your example. The joint probability distribution assigns probability 0.5 to the line y = x and y = -x. This is not surprising. Conditional on X, the random variable Y is either X or -X with equal probablity.

Answer (score 0):

*Graphical comment.*

A few simulated values illustrate that the joint distribution
consists of points on two lines through the origin with respective
slopes $\pm 1.$

For clarity, I have shown only $B = 100$ pairs $(x_i, y_i).$
The correlation $r$ of the x and y samples is nearly $0.$ More
points would typically give $r$ closer to $0$---and a plot in
which it would be difficult to discern individual points.
However, by a symmetry argument, one can prove that the
population correlation $\rho = 0.$

However, the two random variables are not independent:
$P(-.5 < X < .5) >0$ [cyan boundaries] and $P(1 < Y < 1.5) > 0$
[orange boundaries], but $P(-.5 < X < .5,\, 1 < Y < 1.5) = 0$ [rectangle of intersection].

[image]

Normal quantile plots of the marginals on $X$ and $Y$ seem consistent
with normality.

[image]

In case it is of interest, R code to make the two figures is shown below.

```
# First plot
set.seed(517)
B = 100
x = rnorm(B, 0, 1)
b = rbinom(B, 1 , .5)
y = (2*b - 1)*x
cor(x,y)
[1] 0.05892789   # aprx r = 0
plot(x,y,pch=20)
 abline(v=c(-.5,.5), col="cyan3")
 abline(h=c(1,1.5), col="orange3")

# Second plot
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(x);  qqnorm(y)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```